# beforeunload event handler not writing localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to add localStorage when a user leaves the webpage (either through refreshing or closing and reopening to the url again). My browser is the latest version of Chrome. I'm using React.

```js
window.document.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("color", "red");
})
    
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("color"));
```

What I expect:

When I first run the script, `null` is logged. When I leave the webpage and open it again, I expect `'red'` to be logged.

What I get: `null` consistently being logged.

Comment: Hi, if you are using react you can update the local storage on component unmount. Did you try it?

Comment: @Kurosaki_Ishigo Your suggestion works. Shouldn't 'beforeunload' event still fire though? Or does it not fire because we're using React?

Comment: It seems to work when you declare it inside componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", myFunction);
}, but not inside the component constructor.

Comment: @Kurosaki_Ishigo You're right thanks so much for that. Did you know that beforehand, did you read something or did you just test it?

Comment: I was testing the beforeunload in the different life cycle methods. And only works in componentDidMount. If you find any docs, let me to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the beforeunload handler to the Document, rather than to the Window (where the event is dispatched).

The following code works for me in Chrome and Firefox:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("color", "red");
})
```